# When using run-python, how do I keep my window orientation in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, python.el

I have 2 buffers open in emacs, vertically split. One buffer is a .py file, another buffer is the run-python buffer.

When I C-c C-c, my .py code to the run-python buffer, the buffer changes from vertical to horizontal orientation, and it's driving me hair-rippingly mad. I just installed neotree, but otherwise, I'm not sure why this is happening. If you know of a solution to force emacs to stay C-x 3 instead of adjusting the orientation to horizontal, please let me know.

I just nuked my ~/.emacs and ~/.emacs.d and this auto horizontal split when sending code to the *Python* buffer is still happening, so it isn't my ~/.emacs

Comment: I can't reproduce, but I have a vague memory of this behaviour in some condition, don't recall which.. Can you list system, packages and versions, and we will try to find the culprit. Also how do you start the interperter?

Comment: `M-x run-python` or in a .py file `C-c C-c` should do it. I'm simply installing emacs from `apt` in ubuntu, and then trying to `M-x run-python` and it will only open vertical, even if I already have `C-x 3` going.

Comment: and if you try to start the python process with C-c C-p?